# Return derived object pointer in base class object

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

i have the following problem and i do not know why this does not work. The compiler does not produce any errors, but when i execute the code, it crashes.

I have a base class Message and a derived class MessageA.

```
class Message{

protected:

Message(){}

public:

virtual ~Message(){}

virtual void setType(int type) = 0;
virtual int  getType() = 0;

protected:

int type;

};

class MessageA : public Message

{
public:
MessageA(const uint32_t cid);
MessageA();

~CanMessage();


void setCID(const uint32_t cid);


void setType(int type);
int  getType();


uint32_t getCID();

private:

uint32_t cid;

};
```

In order to be flexible which kind of message i will provide as argument to the function receive i selected argument type Message* message.

```
bool ReceiveSingle(Message* message)
{

message = new MessageA(0x53);

return true;

}
```

The function is called in another function where operations should be performed on the returned pointer:

```
Message* temp_message; //Global variable

/*

....

*/

ReceiveSingle(temp_message)
{

    MessageA* temp = static_cast<MessageA*>(temp_message);

    int cid = temp->getCID();  // This operation does not work !!!!!       

}
```

So i want to keep the argument of `ReceiveSingle` flexible and selected the base class type Message*. The function itself creates a derived object pointer and should return it via the global base object pointer `temp_message*`. Later it should be possible to access the variables of the derived object. The static cast works, but when i execute `getCID()` te programm crashes. I can not find any solution for this bug.

It would be nice if someone could help me!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm not sure you have the syntax of your `ReceiveSingle` function right.  You don't have a return type, and you're not specifying a type for temp_message (which will be overriding the global temp_message variable)...  Depending on your compiler they may be defaulting to void and int respectively.

Comment: @Majenko Hint: That one is a function call.

Comment: Is it?  It doesn't look like a function call to me.  Where is the terminating ;  ...?  Why are there { and } after it?  Why is it in the same scope as the global variable definition?

Comment: @Majenko I'm pretty sure it's meant to be (considering the declaration is just above). The `{` and `}` are for declaring a nested scope block.

Comment: I am sorry the { and } are wrong and after ReceiveSingle(temp_message) should be a ;

Comment: It may be meant to be, but it's wrong.  Maybe there's some important context missing...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick and valid solution:

```
ReceiveSingle(Message** message) {

    MessageA* new_message = new MessageA(0x53);

    *message = new_message;

    return true;

}
```

And in order to call `ReceiveSingle(Message** message)` with `Message* temp_message` use

```
ReceiveSingle(&temp_message);
```

Then to get access to the MessageA object stored in temp_message use a static cast:

```
MessageA* tempA = static_cast<MessageA*>(temp_message);
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you assign to temp_message, it might just be a Message not a MessageA. 
Use dynamic_cast instead of the static_cast and than check it temp is nullptr/NULL. If it is NULL temp_message is a Message not a MessageA.

Comment: I will always assign a derived object to temp_message. So never Message, but always MessageA or MessageB and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are going to *statically* cast the pointer, you are not really going to take advantage of dynamic polymorphism.

My suggestion is to use static polymorphism instead:

```
template<class Type>
auto func(const Type& t) {
    int cid = t.getCID();
    // ...
}
```

And then use an `std::unique_ptr` (or any other smart pointer) on the outside:

```
auto message = std::unique_ptr<MessageA>(new MessageA(0x53));
auto ret     = func(*message);
```

---

The original problem is that:

```
bool ReceiveSingle(Message* message) {
    message = new MessageA(0x53);
    return true;
}
```

is not really modifying the passed pointer. Quick fix:

```
bool ReceiveSingle(Message*& message) {
//                         ^
    message = new MessageA(0x53);
    return true;
}
```

But this is a terrible idea mainly because you are using naked pointers.

Comment: So message is the argument of function `ReceiveSingle(Message* message)`? The class which provides `ReceiveSingle()` implements a interface in order to provide different implementations of `ReceiveSingle()` for the different derived Message types. The method which calls actually `ReceiveSingle()` should not need to no which kind of derived Message is processed.Hence the function which calls `ReceiveSingle()`should provide a Message* object to the function via the argument. `ReceiveSingle()`should create a derived message and store it in the provided argument `Message*`.

Comment: The calling function should be able to provide this `Message`object to the outside and the outside only knows which derived type is contained in `message*`object.

Comment: I hope that helps to understand what i try to achieve ;)